# How to get value based on link click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have four links each link will pass different values based on link selection
link1,link2,link3,link4 , if i select first link it should pass values of "sample1" ,where if i select a link2 it should pass value of "sample2",alternatively for link3 value is "sample3" and link4 value is "samplle4".

IN asp.net codebehind

Comment: What about showing some code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [get parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) like:

```
http://example.com?param=sample1
```

you get the parametre on code behind using the Request as:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["param"]
```